Having lining numbers with cfr-lm
I'm trying to use oldstyle numbers only in my body text using pdfLaTeX.
Looking at other questions, I had the idea to use the cfr-lm package and then try to come back with lining numbers in : sectioning, figure counters, heads, enumerations, footnotes.
I've done that :
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}


\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\fontfamily{clm}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{\fontfamily{clm}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{{\fontfamily{clm}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{{\fontfamily{clm}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{{\fontfamily{clm}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{{\fontfamily{clm}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic{subparagraph}}}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\section{test}

\subsection{test}

\subsubsection{test}

\subsubsection{test}

\end{document}

As I added in the comments, it works for sectioning.
I'm still looking for ideas for the rest.

OK, I've found a solution myself ! Just needed to replace lmr by clm.

\usepackage{sectsty} \chapterfont{\lstyle} \allsectionsfont{\lstyle} will also get the job done for sectioning headers. (\lstyle is a macro that's provided by the cfr-lm package.)

Are you aware of the posting Numbers outside of Math environment?

I've read it. I think I still need to distinguish numerals of sectioning (lining numbers) from cardinals of text (oldstyle numbers), since sectioning is not part of the same language as text, in my opinion.

Do you want tabular or proportional or a mixture? How are you configuring headers?

clm switches to tabular lining from proportional hanging. That's different from just switching to lining.

I don't think it's a good idea, from a typographer's point of view. Anyway…
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlstyle}{\lstyle}

\labelformat{chapter}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{section}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{subsection}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{subsubsection}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{paragraph}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{subparagraph}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{figure}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{table}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{equation}{\textlstyle{#1}}
\labelformat{enumi}{\textlstyle{#1}}

\allsectionsfont{\lstyle}
\setlist{font=\lstyle}
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\lstyle#1}}
\NewCommandCopy{\org@makecaption}{\@makecaption}
\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{\org@makecaption{\textlstyle{#1}}{#2}}
\NewCommandCopy{\org@numberline}{\numberline}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\org@numberline{\textlstyle{#1}}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}\label{A}

\section{test}\label{B}

\subsection{test}

\subsubsection{test}

\subsubsection{test}

\paragraph{test}

\subparagraph{test}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{C} test
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}

\begin{equation}\label{D}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{Test}\label{E}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{Test}\label{F}
\end{table}

Refs: \ref{A}, \ref{B}, \ref{C}, \ref{D} and \eqref{D}, \ref{E}, \ref{F}

\end{document}



Don't do that to page numbers, please.

It does not work for me on refs and enumeration with your very code, I don't know why (I've given up a little). Why do you think it's a bad idea? In fact, I want only cardinals and dates from texts to be in a different font, in order to distinguish the language from the metalanguage.

@LouisLascaud “It does not work“ is not enough, sorry. For your need I believe it should be the other way around: mark up where you actually want lowercase digits.

I agree, I will look at it that way from now on. Thanks for you help anyway!

Does \textl conflict with something? While it is only a convention, there's a principled distinction between commands ending in style/shape etc. in the support package and the text font commands. Given the code doesn't actually fully work at the moment, I don't know whether that matters. (Though the number style stuff does work as far as I know. At least, it works for me.) cc @LouisLascaud

@cfr I seem to have overlooked the existence of \textl.

@LouisLascaud I know what a cardinal is and what a metalanguage is, but I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you actually want almost all lining figures, just load the package with the relevant options and then switch to hanging when appropriate. But do you really want something like In section 19, I discussed the 1932 mandate ... and have the 19 lining in one case and oldstyle in the other?
